# How to start application at particular time

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to add this facility into my app in which user can set application start time and at that time application get started.
How can i use broadcast receiver to open my app at user specific time.
I am not sure this is possible in android or not?
if you have any idea than please share.
Here is main activity code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.splash);
    AnimationDrawable  splashAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) splashImage.getBackground();
    splashImage.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
    splashAnimation.start();    
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);// start app in 1 min again
    futureDate.setHours(0);
    futureDate.setMinutes(0);
    futureDate.setSeconds(20);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyAppReciever.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis() , sender);}}
```

and this is reciver class code

```
class MyAppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{ public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
startActivity(new Intent(context, Main_Activity.class));
}private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub}}
```

I have added this line to manifest

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="MyAppReciever"></receiver>
```

now my broadcast trigger but i got this error

```
10-02 17:56:27.735: E/AndroidRuntime(9020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.testgui.MyAppReciever: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
```

Thank you

Comment: Please, take a look on my example...

Comment: Try with Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()); nstead of Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);

Comment: I made some change in code..i instead of futureDate I am using calendar object for trigger broadcast in 1 min.. so after 1 min i got force close dialog ..because of "IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Paul D'Ambra said, you can do it with AlarmManager.

Example:

First you need to set the alarm:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);


futureDate.setHours(8);
futureDate.setMinutes(0);
futureDate.setSeconds(0);


Intent intent = new Intent(con, MyAppReciever.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Next You need to create a reciever with some code to execute(ie- starting your app):

```
public class MyAppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    startActivity(new Intent(context, MyApp.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: in this code i just need to take inputs from edit text and insert it into
futureDate.setHours(i);
futureDate.setMinutes(j); Right?

Comment: If you are using edit texts to set the wake up date, then yes, you need only to set the hours, minutes or seconds.

Comment: in your example what is "con " object? like con.getSystemService()

Comment: con is the app context, you can use getBaseContext instead of con.

Comment: in your code lint show me that am is not used , sender is not used and it doesnt work at all for me..

Comment: I don't understood you, what's your problem exactly? Do you got an force close ?

Comment: no i dont get force close..according to ur code it should open my application as i set it for 2 min. but it wont open it.. i will paste code which i write into my app

Comment: Ok, do you call the right activity "MyApp" in the example when you receive the wake up event?

Comment: yup i write" MainActivity " which is a starting activity of my app.. but i think problem is in main class in my eclipse lint shows yellow line on  "am and sender" and when u mouse over it it shows am and sender are not used in code.

Comment: Please, take a look on the working project: http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/alterpages/files/AlarmManagerTutorial.tar.gz

Answer (score 6):

Am just about to walk out of the office so no doubt someone can add a more detailed answer but you need to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific time, even if your application is
>   not currently running.